# jquery ajax request within the joomla modal window

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, joomla, modal-dialog

I am useing modal window of native joomla codes. I am displaying a form wihchi is used to send mail from one user to another. The php,css and js codes are in tmpl file (by using JDocument) of view and js is like that;

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function(){
    $j("#sendMail").click(function(){
        if(document.formvalidator.isValid(this.form)){
            $j("#mailSending").css("display","inline-block");

            $j.ajax({       
                type: \'POST\',
                url: \'index.php?option=mycomponent&tmpl=component&view=members\',
                data: $j("form#mailForm").serialize(),
                success: function(data,xhr,status){
                            $j("#mailSending").css("display","none");
                            $j("#mailMsg").css("display","inline-block");
                            setTimeout(function(){window.parent.SqueezeBox.close()},1000);
                            alert(status);
                         }
            });
        }else{
            $j("#mailMsg").text("'.JText::_('OFFER_EMPTY_FIELDS').'").css("display","inline-block").delay(1000).fadeOut("slow");
        }
    });                 
});';
```

I am tracing the xhr with firebug when I triger the click function to loading icon is shown and task within the controller file is executed. Php file ends like that;

```
$send =& $mailer->Send();
    if ( $send !== true ) {
        echo 'Error sending email: ' . $send->getMessage();
    } else {
        echo 'Mail sent';
    } 
    exit();
```

While the php function process ends the content within the modal window is changes with Mail Sent. But I want to hide the loading .gif and show a message. But the code don't do that. Any idea ?

Comment: did you check the console? are there any errors shows?

Comment: there is a code it repeats an other ajax request every 15seconds and it works fine but when I trigger this code from within the iframe the net tab of firebug it seems to never ends. And ı looked to konsol and that reuqests respons and html tab from the consol tab which is related that request aren't shown. And In headers tab the response header isnt shonw also my firefox is not english I think the translation ot he tab names are cleart to understand.

Comment: And initially the loading gif and message are hidden. While I clic the button gif is shown.

Comment: Is there a way to load a view with tmpl=component to a div rather than iframe with modal... Why joomlas modal doesn't do that.

Comment: yes, you can achieve this with jQuery, I'll paste the code below so it's formatted.

Answer (score 0):

Code to send a form with ajax and insert its returned values into a div

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $("form[name='srchForm']").submit(function(){
        $.get($(this).action, $(this).serialize() + "&tmpl=component&limitstart=0", function(data){
            $m =$('#main'); 
            $m.html(data).delay(10);
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried this thanks but I didn't understand why my code is wrong I find my type of use is much easier and controllabe. Where should I put the code to displaye loading gif when request is start end where to put to code to hide it. And I need to close SqueezBox after it succeed. I little confused.

Comment: After a little trials I finaly understand what you meant the submit event is more useful :) I understand to prevent conventional events. However the get method is little confusing yet. Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

It is funny I love Ricardo's use of jquery instead of this "$j(document).ready(function(){})" but the point is I figured that the button which is used to trigger the ajax is not to set a type of button it has button tag but doesn't have attribute. I think it tries both ajax and normal submit process and it conficts.

Thanks for your helps and sorry for my stupit mistake.